# Django-1.4.1: unable to save object

Tags: django, django-models

My project is working fine with Django-1.2.5 and Djando-1.3.1 but not with Django-1.4.1.

I am not able to save/create an object and getting an error as given below:

```
from entry.models import Entry

import datetime 

from publications.models import Publication

e = Entry(title=u'this is a test headline to test django-1.4.1',
          body_html=u'this is a test body data to test django-1.4.1',
          pub_date=datetime.datetime.now(),
          publication=Publication.objects.get(id=1))

e.save()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/admin/banking_code/contify-banking/entry/models.py", line 112, in save
  super(Entry, self).save()
File "/home/admin/banking_code/contify-banking/django/db/models/base.py", line 463, in save
  self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
File "/home/admin/banking_code/contify-banking/django/db/models/base.py", line 551, in save_base
  result = manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk, using=using, raw=raw)
File "/home/admin/banking_code/contify-banking/django/db/models/manager.py", line 203, in _insert
  return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
File "/home/admin/banking_code/contify-banking/django/db/models/query.py", line 1593, in insert_query
  return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
File "/home/admin/banking_code/contify-banking/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 914, in execute_sql
  return self.connection.ops.fetch_returned_insert_id(cursor)
File "/home/admin/banking_code/contify-banking/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 548, in fetch_returned_insert_id
  return cursor.fetchone()[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Can any one help me out with this?

Comment: does it work if you just create a variable first, as in `p = Publication.objects.get(id=1)` and then just use that when saving your entry? seems like a nicer approach anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Could you verify that a publication object with id = 1 exists? The quickest way to do this is via the python shell:

Run "python manage.py shell" from your django project's home folder then:

```
 >> from publications.models import Publication
 >> p = Publication.objects.get(id=1)
 >> p
```

If this succeeds ( you get back a Publication object with id 1 ) then we'll have to think of a more exotic cause of failure. If it fails, the problem will have been narrowed down to an issue with the definition of the Publication model.

Comment: yes it does exist.
>>> p = Publication.objects.get(id = 1)
>>> p
<Publication: Test Publication>
even i have a database dump in which the project is connected and working fine with Django's older versions

Comment: Maybe it would help to add to the question: snippets of the Model and Publication objects, and to mention whether you are using a custom manager or the built in manager and whether you have overridden / customized the save method